# CSS div dynamic width

Tags: html, css

I got a little problem with the div width.
I show you an image of what I have

[image: Example]
.

There is an outside div that has no specified width, it can be small or big.

On the right we got a image that floats on the right.

The text div contains a dynamic width that fills all the undefined width space. and inside a undefined width text.

What I want is that the overflow of the Text Div is hidden when the text width is more then the Text Div space.

The problem is how to specify a width to get the overflow on a dynamic width ?
If I don't specify any width, the image will go under the text if it's too long.

I hope I was clear enough.

Thank you for your help.

Edit:

Here is a bit of code to be more clear.

```
<div class="outside">
    <img src="img.jpg" class="img"/>
    <div class="text"><p>some text that is too long</p></div>
</div>

<style>
.img {
    float: right;
}
.text {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
```

The problem is that .text doesn't have any specific width, so the overflow doesn't work

Comment: please push your code for better understanding

Comment: wait, hidden in what way? hidden with the width? or is there a height for the text div?

Comment: so it means only the height of the text div will adjust so that it will not overlap the images?

Comment: I edited, no the height must stay the same, it's the width that need to be cut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/vJCgm/1/)

so let me get this straight:

- you want the text to be clipped when they overflow
- however, you want to set limits using the div where it's contained (which is dynamic)

try this

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="myimage.jpg" />
    <div class="flexi"> some long content</div>
</div>

img{
    float:right;
}

.container{
    overflow:hidden;
    zoom:1;
}

.flexi{
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    zoom:1;
}
```

Comment: I'll try this, jsfiddle.net seems to not work for the moment, I'll check later.

Comment: Ah no, it's not exactly what I need, it must be flexi that is overflow:hidden;
I'm going to insert some code

Comment: flexi HAS overflow hidden. look again. container needs overflow hidden only to contain the float.

Comment: Yes but doesn't seem to work... like jsfiddle doesn't work for me, I show you the result. http://resources.darizi.com/en/home/ you will see on the wedding gown part. I know it's not good to give a link but here I don't really understand :-(

Comment: so you want the rating in line with the name am i right? remove `float:left` from `.names` div and add `overflow:hidden` to the containing  `<li>`. and remove the clearing div.

Comment: Oh thank you ! It was the float left that messed up everything !

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions:

One example:

http://jsfiddle.net/SHYZR/

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want that as and when your DIV is filled out by some text, its width should be increased respectively. try out this :

```
div
{
width:150px;
height:150px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Using this, your overflowed text which goes beyond 150px will not be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the width of Text div to occupy a percentage of outer div and leave the remaining space for the image depending on your image size.

[Check here](http://jsfiddle.net/mdV6e/4/)

edited to put the correct link.

Comment: The problem is that the % is not really reliable... jsfiddle.net works for you ?

Comment: Why do you think its not reliable? In what scenario?